# How to interpret the coefficient of a residualized variable in a linear model?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, multicollinearity

I was fitting a linear model and there was strong multicollinearity present in the data. So, I decided to residualize one regressor variable to reduce the multicollinearity and fitted the model again. The beta cofficient for the variable before and after residualizing the variable was same. But should the interpretation of the coefficient be different this time? How is it correctly interpreted?

Any references on the residualization technique would be appreciated.